# Acceleo: dynamically generate HTML grid in a for loop

Tags: html, acceleo

I'm using Acceleo 3.0 to generate some html code from an EMF Model. I have the following code:

```
<div class="ui-grid" style="text-align:center">
    [for ( icon : Icon | self.Icons )]
            <div class="column-a"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
            <div class="column-b"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
            <div class="column-c"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
    [/for]
</div>
```

Now, what I would like to do is to make it fully parametric, incrementally applying classnames in the for loop until I reach a MaxColumns parameter in my model, then starting over from 0. 
I.e, if I have MaxColumns = 3 I would like the following result:

```
<div class="ui-grid" style="text-align:center">
  <div class="column-a"><button data-icon="icon-1"></button></div>
  <div class="column-b"><button data-icon="icon-2"></button></div>
  <div class="column-c"><button data-icon="icon-3"></button></div>
  <div class="column-a"><button data-icon="icon-4"></button></div>
  <div class="column-b"><button data-icon="icon-5"></button></div>
  <div class="column-c"><button data-icon="icon-6"></button></div>
  <div class="column-a"><button data-icon="icon-7"></button></div>
  <div class="column-b"><button data-icon="icon-8"></button></div>
  <div class="column-c"><button data-icon="icon-9"></button></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supposing your `MaxColumn` attribute is onwed by `self` (in the context you describe), you can use the `subSequence(start, end)` operator on `Icons` if this reference is a sequence. Here is the code:

```
<div class="ui-grid" style="text-align:center">
[for ( icon : Icon | self.Icons->subSequence(1, self.MaxAttribute) )]
        <div class="column-a"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
        <div class="column-b"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
        <div class="column-c"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
[/for]
```

If your reference is not a sequence (but ordered, so an OrderedSet):

```
<div class="ui-grid" style="text-align:center">
[for ( icon : Icon | self.Icons->asSequence()->subSequence(1, self.MaxAttribute) )]
        <div class="column-a"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
        <div class="column-b"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
        <div class="column-c"><button data-icon="[iconName/]"></button></div>
[/for]
```

However, keep in mind that if your ref. is not ordered, Acceleo could collect collection elements in a different order for each execution. The use of the `asSequence()` would not change anything.

Also, be careful, collection first index is *1*, **not** *0*.